# Using forwardRef with React - getting missing key prop for element in iterator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `forwardRef` in a `stateless` functional child component like so:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

const Flag = forwardRef(({ children, active, class }, ref) => (
  <div ref={ref} active={active} className={class}>
    {children}
  </div>)
));

export default Flag
```

When I run tests the es-lint rules are throwing an `error` saying:

`Missing "key" prop for element in iterator`

This is how `<Flag/>` is being used:

```
{
  flag.Error &&
  (<Flag type="Error" ref={this.flag}>
    { flag.Error }
  </Flag>)
}
```

**Update: This is caused by an es-lint rule that apparently throws an error whenever you return jsx in a function without a key.
ForwardRef does not require a key.**

Comment: no, it does not require. So there is something else. Can you provide sample code how do you use `<Flag />`?

Comment: forwardRef does return an iterator but I think the linter has a set rule and doesn't understand that a key is not required. I'm going to try and disable the rule for this component. That should resolve the issue.

Comment: are you using the Flag component inside an array.map ?

Comment: That is a logical conclusion. I was not, but the issue is actually caused by an es-lint rule, and can be ignored.